# How to solve clipped FB.ui with SWFObject on Facebook Application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, facebook, firefox, swfobject

I think this is a little problem for you. So I hope it would not waste your time too much.

I built a Facebook Application with Adobe Flex by using [facebook-actionscript-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/). In production, they use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embed Flash content in HTML page.

The problem is, it looks like SWFObject have a problem with FireFox and some browser. So even I set my application's height to 1000px, the Facebook clipped my Flash content to its minimum size. sometime it shows scroll bar.
[image]

Do you have any suggestion, or workaround on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you will have to use [FB.setCanvasSize()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.canvas.setsize/) besides SWFObject in order to re-scale it properly.